# How am I able to update a value of every document in the collection and make it incrementing with every document?

Tags: java, mongodb

I already have a MongoDB Collection that contains several hundreds of documents. These all have a value called "questID". No I have added a function to my application that allows the user to delete a document. Then I would like to make the value "questID" of all remaining documents increasing, which means that the first document has the questID 1 then 2,3,4,5,6,...

How am I able to do this in java with the Mongodb driver?

Thanks and have a nice one.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using `questId` for? Generally speaking, keeping a number like that in sync across all of the documents is going be **really** hard.

Rather than doing that, it might make more sense to calculate `questId` on the way out: when you fetch documents, you can sort by `_id` and iterate through them all to assign the `questId`.

Alternatively, you could construct a different data structure that's better suited for saving the `questIds` of all of your documents (like a redis sorted set).